# What are the port mapping complexities solved by Flannel?

Tags: hadoop, docker, flannel

Suppose, I have 3 Containers running on a single host and we are making a Hadoop cluster,
1 is master and other 2 are slaves(Namenode and datanodes)

And,we need to map ports:

```
docker run -itd -p 50070:50070 --name master centos:bigdata

docker run -itd -p 50075:50075 -p 50010:50010 --name slave1 centos:bigdata
```

Now ports 50075,50010,50070 are busy on host, we cannot map them for slave2

And if we do some random mapping like,

```
docker run -p 123:50075 -p 234:50010 --name slave2 centos:bigdata
```

Then, containers won't be able to communicate and it won't work.

So, Can flannel solve this problem?

Comment: There are multiple Github repos and blogs not using Flannel. ...

Comment: I will look for them..but I want some layman idea of how flannel solves it?

Comment: Where did you find a reference that it did solve it? Besides, Flannel is commonly used in Kubernetes. It just uses reverse proxy lookups and dynamic port allocation. Traefik is an example Docker image for this

Comment: Check this https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes.. that dynamic port allocation part.. flannel will encapsulate packet and forward it to destined service automatically, but it works between hosts.. can it happen if containers are on single host? I'm not yet hands-on with flannel